# How do safely discharge Li-Ion batteries to check full capacity

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, discharge

I regularly have to test old phone batteries in my mobile phone refurbishment business. I need a safe solution to discharge 3.6V batteries. When I buy batteries they come from old stock so I need to discharge them them check how many mAh it still takes. This is difficult and time consuming. In the past I've used a 3.6V light bulb but the process takes forever. I was considering a 3.6V motor but that would probably get warm and break pretty fast. Any suggestion? I know I'm not supposed to completely discharge Li-Ion batteries but these are phone batteries with built-in protection so it should be fine.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to quickly measure the capacity of the battery, right? The easiest way to rapidly discharge the battery would be with an appropriate resistor. But if you want to measure the capacity, then it is better to discharge with a current sink. Just because the math is easier. Time * current = capacity. With the resistor method, current changes over time so you need to integrate.

Comment: Probably you should buy a battery cycler.

Comment: Are the "3.6V" batteries Lithium? A Lithium battery cell is 3.2V when almost dead and is 4.2V when fully charged. If you discharge below about 3.0V then it is ruined. See it at www.batteryuniversity.com . Sometimes the phone has a protection circuit that disconnects the battery when its discharge voltage gets too low.

Comment: If you discharge them too quickly you will get a misrepresentation of their capacity that must be calibrated to the actual capacity with the real load.  For this reason it might be best to make your load roughly equivalent to power draw from a phone and let it take the time it takes and then discharge more rapidly and repeat with a few different batteries.  See how well you can correlate the fast draw time with the more realistic one.  If you use a constant power load or track both current and voltage you will get a more accurate result than with a resistor or constant current load.

Comment: @Audioguru it is an exaggeration to say that if you discharge it below 3.0 it will be ruined. In general the best way to discharge it for testing purposes is according to the cell manufacturer's specification. But a single deep discharge will not destroy the cell.

Comment: You can buy capacity measuring gizmos from the usual absurdly cheap sources. Connect a big resistor (or that bulb) to the output, program the cutoff voltage, and wait. When the voltage falls below cutoff, it stops discharging and displays the capacity.

Comment: Batteryuniversity.com does not show any discharge below 3.0V and says a lithium-ion cell is damaged if discharged lower. Their 3.0V End Of Discharge graphs are also shown in Google images.

Answer (score 2):

Or, try using an electronic load (ex: Tekpower 3710A).

Comment: Thank you, that helped!